# JavaScript generate dynamic input field and getElementById from it

Tags: javascript, html

I use javascript to add a new input field inside the html form.

```
//n is from 1 to 20
$('#formid').find('#transtext').before('ProductName</a><b><u><a id="ProductName'+n+'">N/A</a></u></b>');
```

Then, it would generate the input field with dynamic id, for example,id =ProductName1,id=ProductName2,id=ProductName3......

The Question is how to use javascript to get element id from those dynamic input fields?

```
var productname2 = document.getElementById('ProductName2');
var productname3 = document.getElementById('ProductName3');
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's wrong with the code you've tried?

Comment: are you asking how to write it without jquery? if not, why are you mixing jquery with es5 vanilla? you could just as easily write $('#ProductName2')... else you might want to take a look at querySelector and querySelectorAll

Comment: A couple of notes: `$('#formid').find('#transtext')` can be rewritten as `$('#transtext')`, since IDs are unique to the document. Note that the code is attempting to insert invalid HTML, which jQuery will not allow; basically the string will  be changed to `'<a>Productname</a><b><u><a id="ProductName'+n+'">N/A</a></u></b>'`.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to get the elements until after they've been added to the DOM (i.e., after the call to `before()`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct, is it not working? One problem I foresee is the order execution. Were these codes on page load or in-line during loading?

$ => jquery. So, was the jquery library loaded and executed?

Try putting breakpoints before $('#formid')... and before document.getElementById('ProductName2');
`debugger;`

If you want to getElementById on startup, maybe put it in $.ready